# How do I deal with a possible exception in a Xamarin Forms application deployed to iOS or Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a finished application which I would like to make available to run on the iOS and Android platforms.  I have tested the application as much as possible and it works without problem.  But I know there is always the chance that something might go wrong and I could get an exception.

My question is how can I deal with this or what should I do. What happens on the phone, if a Forms application is deployed and there is an exception.

Would appreciate any advice or even links as to how this is handled.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown and not handled by your code, the app will stop working (i.e. crash).

In order to handle these crashes we are using [MS AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms) (the successor to HockeyApp/Xamarin AppInsights).

You'll have to create a project there (one for each platform), and add the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes/) to your projects. Afterwards you can initialize it with

```
AppCenter.Start("ios={Your App Secret};android={Your App Secret}", 
                typeof(Crashes)); // you'll get the app secrets from appcenter.ms
```

Crashes will be logged to AppCenter now and you'll be informed whenever there is a new crash.

**Please note** that it's best practice (if not required by law), that you ask the user for consent before sending the crash report ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin#ask-for-the-users-consent-to-send-a-crash-log)). You are using the delegate `Crashes.ShouldAwaitUserConfirmation` for that matter. You could for example show an action sheet with [Acr.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/)

```
private bool AwaitUserConfirmation()
{
    // you should of course use your own strings
    UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheet(
        new ActionSheetConfig
        {
            Title = "Oopsie",
            Message = "The app crashed. Send crash to developers.",
            Options = new List<ActionSheetOption>
                      {
                          new ActionSheetOption("Sure", () => Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.Send)),
                          new ActionSheetOption("Yepp, and don't bug be again.", () => Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.AlwaysSend)),
                          new ActionSheetOption("Nope", () => Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.DontSend))
                      }
        });

    return true;
}
```